# git showing version 1.9.1 when installing from apt-get and source

Tags: git

I tried install git via apt-get install git, and from source using these instructions:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-ubuntu-14-04
Either way, if I type in git --version, it says I have 1.9.1, instead of 2.7, which is the latest version.
I tried to purge git, but on re-install, it is still version 1.9.1
Any ideas on what I did wrong?

Comment: If you re-install from apt why would you expect to get a different version?  Remove the one from apt and then you should only have the one you compiled yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the latest version:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge git
```

Then recompile git and reinstall using the instructions (not with apt-get).  Git is split into multiple packages, so if you did used remove instead of autoremove, you were probably still using the apt-get version.